# An analysis of storing hints for passwords?

Tags: encryption, passwords

What are the security implications of asking users to provide password hints?  What are best practices for storing user hints?  What research has been done on using user-supplied password hints to guide password cracker applications?

---

Note - it looks like Adobe's astonishing fail with 130 M reversibly-encrypted passwords, stored together with their hints, will spur the field...  Hat tip to [XKCD](http://xkcd.com) for sharing the news, and the enticing title "greatest crossword puzzle in the history of the world": [1286: Encryptic - explain XKCD](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=1286)

[image: XKCD Comic 1286]

The new GOTCHA method: Generating panOptic Turing Tests to Tell Computers and Humans Apart makes cracking harder, and also brings AI into the field: [Inkblot passwords could help increase online security - UPI.com](http://www.upi.com/Science_News/Blog/2013/11/07/Inkblot-passwords-could-help-increase-online-security/8331383842240/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real world impact of hints on security is large. Sarah Palin's account was hacked because someone figured out her high school.

Hints are essentially public info. They are provided to any untrusted person who clicks "I forgot my password." In that context alone, encrypting them doesn't make much sense. But Adobe proved that storing hints with encrypted passwords provides extra weakness.

In general, the security still has to come down to proper hashing of salted passwords. Storing passwords is insecure. Unhashed passwords are insecure. ECB is insecure. None of their mistakes weren't already common public knowledge, and they were all failures to follow best practices.

Would I recommend encrypting hints? Instead, I'd  recommend they use an out-of-band password reset process (via SMS or some other method) and skip the hints entirely.

Comment: +1 for alternative to hints. I was very annoyed about having to enter a hint for Windows 7 (at least it took a single character, so I just put '.' in).

Answer (score 1):

Two security implications we discussed (before finally opting not to have a password hints feature):

- You have to guard against the user being too specific in their hint.
  (e.g. "My home phone number")
- You have to guard against the user putting some portion of their
  password into the hint itself.

Non-security issues that are still relevant to business processes:

- Additional sign-up fields reduce conversion.
- Some small proportion of people will complain about the presence of a hint field, even if it's optional.

It would be nice to have some hard data from the real world. So if you know anyone in charge of user management whose business process does involve password hints and reset questions, point them to this thread!